# I am having trouble moving a file to a folder in php

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code I am using

```
try
{
    // Execute the query to create the user
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    $elliot =  $_POST['username'];
    $usor =  $elliot.php;
    $myfile = fopen("$elliot.php", "c+") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = "Userpage\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
    rename('$usor', 'usors/$usor');
}
```

Essentially what I am doing is creating a user. When the user is created then what I want to code to do is make a userpage. Then I want the user page to be move to a folder called usors.

My problem is I can create the user page. But I am unable to move the newly created userpage.

Comment: Are you sure that the server user has write permission for the directory you're trying to write to?

Comment: the permissions is   rwxr-xr-x. Should I use that?

Comment: Does the server user (the user executing the PHP code / running Apache or whatever server environment you're using) own the directory? If it doesn't own the directory, then it won't be able to write to it because the permissions are:

Owner - read/write/execute
Group - read/execute
World/all users - read/execute

Comment: This `$elliot.php` is a syntax error.

Comment: @chris85 didn't notice that. Good point.

Comment: @zDoude it's depend of owner: if owner is the same as Apache, they will works. Otherwise you can: 1) change the owner of directory; 2) change permissions to 0775 if Apache is in the same group of dir owner; 3) change permissions to 0777 (security issue: anyone can write to directory).

Comment: Why not have a dynamic page rather than individual pages for each user?

Comment: actually i do have a dynamic page.

Comment: So why make each user have a page. Make `user.php` then associate it by their username or id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, variables do not get parsed in single quotes.

```
rename('$usor', 'usors/$usor');
```

You need to use double quotes

```
rename("$usor", "usors/$usor");
```

Sidenote: `"usors/$usor"` will only be accessible if you are running your script just outside the `usors` folder. Make sure the path is correctly set.

Then this `$usor =  $elliot.php;` you need to remove the `.php` from there.

```
$usor =  $elliot;
```

Since you are referencing `$elliot =  $_POST['username'];`

And of course, making sure that proper permissions are set.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Seeing that you are using a POST array, make sure the form you are using is using a POST method and that the input for it bears the matching name attribute.

Comment: @zDoude ok. Let me know if you have any trouble and check for errors also.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `rename` php function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) but be sure the user running your php script (apache ?) has enough rights.